# org.apache.coyote. CloseNowException: Failed write

Tags: java, http, tomcat

org.apache.coyote. CloseNowException: Failed write
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http110utputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http110utputBuffer.java:548)~[tomcat-embed-cor
e-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.391
at org.apache.coyote.httpll.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:110)~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.
jar!/:9.0.39]
atorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http110utputBuffer.doWrite(Http110utputBuffer.java:193)~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.
39]
at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:601)~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realwriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:339)~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.
39]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:776)~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9

dont appear this error

Comment: I am facing same issue for Asynch rest api to download a file. Any one have any clue on this?